# BlueTooth Low Energy Advertising Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

As a peripheral device (android), i am sending out an advertisement. I am attempting to retrieve an RSSI value from a central device that gets connects to the peripheral. I was advised to use readRemoteRssi() and read the value from its callback onReadRemoteRssi.

```
 private class BleCallBack extends BluetoothGattCallback {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
                                        int newState) {

       if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {

            mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
        }
    }

    public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("BluetoothGatt ReadRssi[%d]", rssi));

        }

    }
};
```

However i am still unable to read the rssi value even after successful connection.

Comment: Does BluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi() return true?  If so, what is the status code you're having returned?

Comment: It does not. I think my logic is incorrect. I have a callback that extends the AdvertiseCallback class which is from what i understand essential. So is it even possible for me to create this callback that extends BlueToothGattCallback so that i can use onReadRemoteRssi. Is there a way to merge both Callbacks together?